# cocos2d version2.0 singleton invalid

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, singleton

I use cocos2d version2.0 build a game, not use ARC, find a problem: the singleton is invalid.

I use two singleton MACRO, the problem same.

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_INTERFACE
#define SINGLETON_INTERFACE(CLASSNAME)                  \
    +(CLASSNAME*) sharedManager;
#endif

#ifndef SINGLETON_IMPLEMENTATION
#define SINGLETON_IMPLEMENTATION(CLASSNAME)             \
                                                        \
+(CLASSNAME*) sharedManager {                           \
    static dispatch_once_t pred;                        \
    static CLASSNAME* shared##CLASSNAME = nil;          \
    dispatch_once( &pred, ^{                            \
    shared##CLASSNAME = [[self alloc] init]; });        \
    return shared##CLASSNAME;                           \
}                                                           
#endif
```

or

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_INTERFACE
#define SINGLETON_INTERFACE(CLASSNAME)              \
    +(CLASSNAME*) sharedManager;
#endif

#ifndef SINGLETON_IMPLEMENTATION            
#define SINGLETON_IMPLEMENTATION(CLASSNAME)         \
\
static CLASSNAME* shared##CLASSNAME = nil;          \
\
+(CLASSNAME*) sharedManager                         \
{                                                   \
    if (shared##CLASSNAME != nil) {                 \
        return shared##CLASSNAME;                   \
    }                                               \
\
    @synchronized(self) {                           \
        if (shared##CLASSNAME == nil) {             \
            shared##CLASSNAME = [[self alloc] init];\
        }                                           \
    }                                               \
\
    return shared##CLASSNAME;                       \
}                                                   \
\
+(id) allocWithZone:(NSZone*)zone                   \
{                                                   \
    @synchronized(self) {                           \
        if (shared##CLASSNAME == nil) {             \
            shared##CLASSNAME = [super allocWithZone:zone]; \
            return shared##CLASSNAME;               \
        }                                           \
    }                                               \
    NSAssert(NO, @ "[" #CLASSNAME " alloc] explicitly called on singleton class.");   \
    return nil;                                     \
}                                                   \
\
-(id) copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone                    \
{                                                   \
    return self;                                    \
}                                                   \
\
-(id) retain                                        \
{                                                   \
    return self;                                    \
}                                                   \
\
-(unsigned) retainCount                             \
{                                                   \
    return UINT_MAX;                                \
}                                                   \
\
-(oneway void) release                              \
{                                                   \
}                                                   \
\
-(id) autorelease                                   \
{                                                   \
    return self;                                    \
}
#endif
```

use:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MenuScene sharedManager]];
```

The MenuScene show again, but any buttons(CCMenu) or other elements(CCNode) not have response. 
I mean the first call, scene everything is ok, when the call again, scene is show but menu or other elements not have response.
But in cocos2d v1.0 running very good.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I override the "cleanup" without "[super cleanup]", like this:

```
-(void) dealloc
{   
    [super cleanup];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) cleanup 
{
    //
}
```

Now, the scene running singleton ok, but it safely?

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably lies with CCDirector performing "cleanup" operations on your Scene's children.

cocos2d v2.0 adds use of blocks in several cases, which get released during "cleanup" that happens regardless of whether your singleton stays in-memory.

From the v2.0 migration guide:

> Setting the cleanup flag to YES might cause side-effects in your application's logic which is still making implicit references to freed resources. CCMenuItems, which use blocks internally to launch actions, might be giving problems and not launching an action, assuming you have removed the item from its parent node with the cleanup flag activated and added it back, is one of the telling signs. Simply changing the flag to NO should be enough.

Migration Guide: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:migrate_to_v2.0#ccsprite

---

Offhand, I suggest you either:

- Find a way to safely prevent "cleanup" being called on your singleton's children.
- Or: Keep everything in memory as children of a CCLayer that you show/hide instead of using the scene mechanism.
- Or: Not use a singleton and recreate your scene each time.